# Why is my solution to $ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 2\frac{dy}{dx} + 5y = 10\sin x $ wrong?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is what I did to find out the general solution :-

$$ (D^2 - 2D + 5)y = 10\sin x \\ 
\therefore \text{Auxiliary equation is } m^2 - 2m + 5 = 0 \\
\rightarrow m = \frac{-(-2) \pm \sqrt{(-2)^2 - 4.1.5}}{2.1} \\
= \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4 - 20}}{2} \\
= \frac{2 \pm 4i}{2} = 1 \pm 2i \\
\therefore \text{Complementary function = } e^x(C_1\cos 2x + C_2 \sin 2x) \\
\text{Now, particular integral } = \frac{10 \sin x}{D^2 - 2D + 5} \\
= \frac{10 \sin x}{-1^2 -2D + 5} = \frac{10 \sin x}{4 - 2D} = \frac{5 \sin x}{2 - D} \\
= \frac{5\sin x}{2(1-\frac{D}{2})} = \frac{5}{2}\left(1-\frac{D}{2}\right)^{-1}\sin x \\ 
= \frac{5}{2}\left(1 + \frac{D}{2} + ...\right)\sin x \\
= \frac{5}{2}\left(\sin x + \frac{D}{2}\sin x\right) = \frac{5}{2}\left(\sin x + \frac{\cos x}{2}\right) = \frac{5}{4}(2\sin x + \cos x) \\
\text{Now, } y = \text{CF + PI} \\
\therefore y = e^x(C_1\cos 2x + C_2 \sin 2x) + \frac{5}{4}(2\sin x + \cos x) $$

But the answer given in the book is :-

$$ y = e^x(C_1 \cos 2x + C_2 \sin 2x) + 2 \sin x + \cos x $$

Comment: Did you check your answer satisfy the equation?

Comment: side note you can rescale $C_1, C_2$ to be anything i.e $C_1 =  \frac{5}{4}\bar{C}_1$ etc. Though typically these questions you would expect the same coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$PI = \frac{1 }{D^2-2D+5}(10\sin x) = 10\frac{1}{4-2D}\sin x = \frac{5}{2-D}{IP e^{ix}}$

$PI = IP\frac{5}{2-i}e^{ix} = 5IP (\frac{2}{5}+\frac{i}{5})(\cos x +i\sin x)$

$PI = IP (2\cos x +i\cos x +2i\sin x - \sin x) = \cos x + 2\sin x $

> $$PI = \cos x + 2\sin x $$

You can't simply write $(1-\frac{D}{2})^{-1} = (1+\frac{D}{2}\cdots)$ because $D^2(\sin x) , D^3(\sin x) \cdots $ exist.

If it were simply $x^n$, then we can take up to only $D^n(x^n)$ and take $D^{n+1}(x^n) = D^{n+2}(x^n) =\cdots = 0$, ***but not in this case.***

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get the right answer with your method.

After you render

$PI=10(1-\dfrac{D}{2})^{-1}(\sin x)$

you then apply a difference of squares factorization to get

$(1-\dfrac{D}{2})^{-1})=(1+\dfrac{D}{2})(1-\dfrac{D^2}{4})^{-1}$

and then observe that when $D$ operates on $\sin x$ then $D^2=-1$.  So

$(1-\dfrac{D}{2})^{-1}=(1+\dfrac{D}{2})(1+\dfrac{1}{4})^{-1}=\color{blue}{\dfrac{4}{5}}(1+\dfrac{D}{2})$

thus getting the factor of $4/5$ you missed.

Answer (score 1):

P.I. $=\frac{1}{D^2-2D+5}10 \sin x$

$=10 \frac{1}{(-1^2-2D+5)} \sin x$

$=10 \frac{1}{4-2D} \sin x$

$=5 \frac{1}{2-D} \sin x$

$=5 \frac{2+D}{4-D^2} \sin x$

$=5 \frac{2+D}{4+1^2} \sin x$

$=(2+D) \sin x$

$= 2 \sin x + \cos x$

---

> - If $f(D)$ can be expressed as $\phi(D^2)$ and $\phi(-a^2)\neq 0$, then
>
> $1.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \sin ax=\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \sin ax = \frac{1}{\phi(-a^2)} \sin ax$
>
> $2.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \cos ax=\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \cos ax = \frac{1}{\phi(-a^2)} \cos ax$
>
> **Note:** If $f(D)$ can be expressed as $\phi(D^2)=D^2+a^2$, then $\phi(-a^2)= 0$.
>
> $1.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \sin ax =\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \sin ax=x\frac{1}{\phi'(D^2)} \sin ax= x \frac{1}{2D} \sin ax= -\frac{x}{2a} \cos ax$.
>
> $2.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \cos ax =\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \cos ax=x\frac{1}{\phi'(D^2)} \cos ax=  x \frac{1}{2D} \cos ax= \frac{x}{2a} \sin ax$.
>
> where $\phi'(D^2)\equiv\frac{d}{dD}\phi(D^2)$
>
> - If $f(D)$ contains odd power also, say, $f(D)=f_1(D^2)+Df_2(D^2)$, where $f_1(-a^2)\neq 0$ and $f_2(D-a^2)\neq 0$
>
> $1.$ $$\frac{1}{f_1(D^2)+Df_2(D^2)} \sin ax=\frac{1}{f_1(-a^2)+Df_2(-a^2)} \sin ax=\frac{1}{p+qD} \sin ax=(p-qD)\frac{1}{(p+qD)(p-qD)} \sin ax=(p-qD)\frac{1}{p^2-q^2D^2} \sin ax=\frac{1}{p^2+q^2a^2} (p-qD) \sin ax=\frac{1}{p^2+q^2a^2} (p  \sin ax - qa \cos ax)$$
>
> $2.$ $$\frac{1}{f_1(D^2)+Df_2(D^2)} \cos ax=\frac{1}{f_1(-a^2)+Df_2(-a^2)} \cos ax=\frac{1}{p+qD} \cos ax=(p-qD)\frac{1}{(p+qD)(p-qD)} \cos ax=(p-qD)\frac{1}{p^2-q^2D^2} \cos ax=\frac{1}{p^2+q^2a^2} (p-qD) \cos ax=\frac{1}{p^2+q^2a^2} (p  \cos ax + qa \sin ax)$$

---

For your case,

P.I. $=\frac{5}{2}(1-\frac{D}{2})^{-1} \sin x$

$ = \frac{5}{2}(1+\frac{D}{2}+\frac{D^2}{4}+\frac{D^3}{8}+\cdots) \sin x$

$=\frac{5}{2} (\sin x +\frac{1}{2}\cos x-\frac{1}{4}\sin x - \frac{1}{8} \cos x + \cdots)$

$=\frac{5}{2} \{(1-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{16}+\cdots) \sin x+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{32}+\cdots) \cos x\}$

$=\frac{5}{2}(1-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{16}+\cdots)\{\sin x +\frac{1}{2} \cos x\}$

$=\frac{5}{2}\frac{4}{5}\{\sin x +\frac{1}{2} \cos x\}$

$=2\sin x + \cos x$

The infinite  series $1-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{16}+\cdots$ is  a geometric series with first term $1$  and common ratio $-\frac{1}{4}$.

So
$1-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{16}+\cdots=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{4}{5}$